# Embed VSTS unit tests in standalone application

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio there is the so called 'test view' that provides an overview of all unit tests within the current solution/project.

I wonder if it is possible to embed this view into a standalone application. The idea is to have a standalone application that lets you run special integration tests on a staging system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view is part of Visual Studio. Even if it was possible to do what you ask about, it's not likely to be legal, as it's part of a licensed product.

For scenarios such as this, you would be much better off with an open source unit testing framework such as [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) or [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/), where reuse is much more open.